# Ruby Rails Environment Completely Down about Paths, installation and brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment

and Thank you for Helping me!

Long story short, I put this in the terminal

```
curl https://raw.github.com/gist/1688857/rbenv.sh | sh ; rbenv global 1.9.3-p327-perf
```

I ended up downloading/installing ruby over my current ruby/rails. I stopped it in time but it was too late. Both my rails and my ruby commands didn't work .....

Originally I installed railsinstaller to get my rails/ruby up and running.

I did rvm implode, removed rvm path in .bash_profile, 
removed /etc/rvmrc file as well. I figured the rmv clash with the new ruby that I downloaded.

Originally I used railsinstaller to get ruby/rails up and running.

Then I tried to install railsinstaller but it didn't work! I later uninstalled railsinstaller because I want to try brew.

Here is my .bashrc profile

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

Here is what I get when I run brew doctor

```
Warning: Setting DYLD_* vars can break dynamic linking.
    Set variables:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Warning: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.

Warning: Experimental support for using Xcode without the "Command Line Tools".
You have only installed Xcode. If stuff is not building, try installing the
"Command Line Tools for Xcode" package provided by Apple.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

autoconf
libtool
```

(I tried brew link above)

```
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/ifnames
/usr/local/bin/ifnames may already exist.
/usr/local/bin may not be writable.
```

same thing happen with libtool

```
Warning: Your Xcode is configured with an invalid path.
You should change it to the correct path:
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

When I run brew install ruby .......

```
NOTE: By default, gem installed binaries will be placed into:
   /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin

 You may want to add this to your PATH.
 Warning: Could not link ruby. Unlinking...
 Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
 The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
 You can try again using `brew link ruby'
     ==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0: 877 files, 18M, built in 2.7 minutes
```

---

There are bash commands that I can not access. I have to source my bashprofile everytime to get some bash commands to work.....

---

I am new to rails and I am developing a rails app. The rails mvc concepts are easy to grasp, but I didn't pay much attention to. 
-paths
-environments
-rbenv
-rvm
-brew
-bash commands

etc

This is the type of thing where you start making the app after installing everything and don't quite know how ruby/rails work under the hood when something breaks.

If someone can point me to the right direction. I will love your help. I will try to research this further myself.

Thanks!
If you need more info please let me know and thanks!

---

HI HERE IS MY UPDATE

Thanks! so I installed xcode, 
I went through this tutorial 
https://coderwall.com/p/auvm9g
and installed everything successfully but my computer can't find the ruby/rails that I installed. It came on when the installation finished but I lost it after I exit the terminal.

---

I did brew doctor

```
Warning: Setting DYLD_* vars can break dynamic linking.
Set variables:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
```

---

```
Here is my .bashrc

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin


export PATH="/usr/local:$PATH"ls
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

---

Here is my .bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into    shell session *as a function*
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

---

ruby -v

```
rbenv: ruby: command not found

The `ruby' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  1.9.3-p286
```

---

rails -v

```
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  1.9.3-p286
```

---

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

```
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/judyngai/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/judyngai/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/judyngai/.bash_profile /Users/judyngai/.zlogin.
Installing rvm gem in 1 gemsets ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass


Upgrade Notes:



 * WARNING: Above files contains `PATH=` with no `$PATH` inside, this can break RVM,
 for details check https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525
 to avoid this warning append #PATH.

 * No new notes to display.
```

---

my .rvm and .benv are in my Users/judyngai/.rvm

I am pretty sure I have a paths problem, if someone can enlighten me I will be really happy and grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going on.

First off, I haven't used railsinstaller, but it looks like a bad deal.  Many of these "one-click-install" applications end up leaving you in a mess like you have here.  I recommend removing everything rails installer has done and following something like this guide to get you going: https://coderwall.com/p/auvm9g.  That does each part separately.

But, if you want to try and fix what you got...

First, looks you have some issues with homebrew according to `brew doctor`. Largest of which is you need to install Xcode Command Line Tools.

That should also take care the autoconf and libtool warnings.

Looks like you also need change permissions on you /uar/local directory since that's where homebrew puts everything.

Second, installing Ruby through brew is a bad idea.  I recommend either rbenv or rvm.

Comment: Hi I changed the permissions on usr/local and installed xcode/command line tools, the autoconf and libtool warnings are gone. I uninstalled railsinstaller. I have also gone through the tutorial but now I got some new errors which I pasted above. Thanks I got pretty far because of your help !